# Is it possible to connect two web parts which are located on different pages? [SharePoint 2010]

Tags: web-applications, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

First web part (lets call it WebPart1) is located in Page1.aspx and another web part (lets call it WebPart2) is located in Page2.aspx. How can I connect WebPart2 to WebPart1? I want to use "Get filter from" type of connection.
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, NO
ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can pass params in query string.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft says it is possible at this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA101785157.aspx) but how to connect, I am still searching.